# Any solutions for announcing policy changes?

Tags: 7

We want a slide-up notification to announce a change to the terms of use on our site, only shown 1x/user.

Is there any way to do this? Or would it be better to use a block and some custom js to do the user-limitation?

Comment: Have a look at the **[this](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35152/)** ...

Comment: Another solution/approach is to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) modules as explained **[here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167349/how-to-display-terms-and-conditions-before-starting-a-download-possibly-using/167540#167540)**

Comment: Thanks @Pierre.Vriens! What we ended up doing was adding a js/css to the theme. The JS looked for a evidence that the user has already seen or dismissed the announcement through using localStorage (or a cookie fallback). If they didn't see it, then it would append a DIV to #footer and use jQuery animate to set its CSS to show up in a fixed position at the bottom. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpMns/) was a great example of how to get the footer announcement showing up.